# NSRangeException Error with NSArray - While setting image view in another ViewController

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode

I'm getting an image from the AppDelegate, then setting it to the ViewController's table.imageView property. It's throwing me an NSRangeException:

```
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSRangeException', reason: '-[__NSCFArray     objectAtIndex:]: index (2) beyond bounds (2)'
```

I made sure my array and rows are counted by [array count]. Very confused. Here's the code:

```
#pragma mark - viewWillAppear
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {

PBAppDelegate *dataObject = (PBAppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
NSString *titleRead = dataObject.title;
NSString *descRead = dataObject.desc;
UIImage *imageRead = dataObject.image;


if ([titleRead isEqualToString:@"" ] || [descRead isEqualToString:@""]) {
    // it's nil
} else {
    if (titleRead) {
        [data addObject:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:titleRead, descRead, imageRead, nil]];
        dataObject.title = @"";
        dataObject.desc = @"";
        [tableView reloadData];
    }

    NSUserDefaults *dataDefaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    [dataDefaults setObject:[NSArray arrayWithArray:data] forKey:@"dataArrayKey"];
    [dataDefaults synchronize];
}

}

#pragma mark - viewDidLoad
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
[super viewDidLoad];
data = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

self.data = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"dataArrayKey"];
[tableView reloadData];
}

#pragma mark - Table Datasource
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath     *)indexPath {

static NSString *cellIdentifier = @"MyCell";
UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentifier];

if (!cell) {
    cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:cellIdentifier];
}

cell.textLabel.text = [[data objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectAtIndex:0];
cell.detailTextLabel.text = [[data objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectAtIndex:1];
cell.imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:[[data objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectAtIndex:2]];
cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryDisclosureIndicator;

return cell;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It's probably this line:

```
cell.imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:[[data objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectAtIndex:2]];
```

The console output says there are 2 elements in the array.  Elements start at 0; so you can access objectAtIndex:0 and objectAtIndex:1.  Two would be the 3rd element of the array, and is out of bounds.

Sorry if that's all obvious, just taking a quick stab... Enjoy. :)

**EDIT**
Actually, the issue could be that `imageRead` is nil when you add it to the array.  That would cause the array to have only 2 elements in it.  You may check for that, and/or use [NSNull null] if you don't have an image...

Comment: In your code, you have an array of arrays. 0=title, 1=desc, 3=image.  You put them in here: [data addObject:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:titleRead, descRead, imageRead, nil]].  My theory is that "imageRead" is nil when you insert it.  That means you're doing this [data addObject:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:titleRead, descRead, nil, nil]] - ending your array 1 element to early; resulting in the exception when you try to pull the data out.  You should check for the nil and perhaps replace it by using [NSNull null] which will give you a "null object" that you can stuff into your array.

Comment: Personally, I'd recommend you pull our the inner array and turn it into a simple object (product.m or whatever) with properties for title, desc, and image.  Then create an array of those.  Your code will be more readable and this crash will almost certainly go away.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the array actually has 3 elements by doing something like this:

```
NSArray *array = [data objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
if ([array count] > 2)
{
 cell.imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:[array objectAtIndex:2]];
}
```